# TextBlock when run not displaying entire text

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, textblock

I am building a wpf application, where my text block text is fading out when the application is run.
Code is

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="RSP Level" Width="78" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54.2,3,0,398.6" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Hex" Width="60" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="157.2,36,0,367.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.993,0.976" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Hex" Width="29" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="31.2,35,0,368.6" RenderTransformOrigin="1.91,0.08" />
        <TextBlock Text="Link" Width="29" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="31.2,59,0,344.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.993,0.976"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Application" Width="61" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="32.2,83,0,320.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.993,0.976"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Physical" Width="66" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="158.2,61,0,342.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.993,0.976" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Link" Width="35" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="158.2,85,0,318.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.993,0.976"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Application" Width="69" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="3" Margin="157.2,108,0,295.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.993,0.976" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting `Height="Auto" for the textblocks.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i tried auto, same result..

Comment: I can't reprodice the issue. Your code works good by my side. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show the complete code. You are missing the ColumnDefinitions and CheckBoxes... Use nested StackPanels or add RowDefinitions to your Grid. Then each column of a row contains a horizontal StackPanel containing a TextBlock and a CheckBox. You would need two columns for this.

Comment: thank-you everyone for the help. i grouped the text blocks in a stack panel and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way to align contents. You can use [StackPanel](https://www.wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html) to place child elements below or beside each other. If you use [Grid](https://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html), define Rows and Columns. Using margins is not a proper way. Read more WPF about layouts [here](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html).